# Split string into two separate strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I have a name that is just one string for example "LUKE CARROLL" and I want to split this string into first name and last name. So I just need to split the string where there is a space.
So I would end up with something like:

```
string FirstName = "Luke";
string LastName = "Carroll";
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `string[] parts = myString.Split(' ');`?

Comment: Names are complex: `Van der Graaf`, `Charles de Batz-Castelmore d'Artagnan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split()`

```
    string name= "LUKE CARROLL";
    string[] tmp = name.Split(' ');
    string FirstName = tmp [0]; 
    string LastName = tmp [1];
```

Comment: `textbox2.text= tmp[0].SubString(0,tmp[0].Length-4).TrimStart('+').TrimStart('0');`???